# Pgfplots labels in contour plot exported from python

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, labels, python

I use python to draw a lot of contourplots which I export to a tikz figure. However, when exporting the tikz figure the labels are not exported. And it does not matter whether I insert labels on the lines or add them to a colorbar they are not exported. I tried to find a solution but unfortunately python exports the contourplots with the \path method instead of the contourmethod meaning that most methods to add a colorbar or labels inside the plot do not work.

There are too many plots and labels to add them all by hand, so I was wondering if anyone knows a solution to add plots. I added an example python export.

```
This file was created by matplotlib2tikz v0.5.15.

\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.161290322580645,1,0.806451612903226}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.3,1}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1,0.407407407407408,0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.806451612903226,1,0.161290322580645}

\begin{axis}[
title={Simplest default with labels},
xmin=-3, xmax=2.80000000000001,
ymin=-2, ymax=1.8,
axis on top
]
\path [draw=blue!50.0!black] (axis cs:0.718531200553679,-0.0767608872850903)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-0.179470474200398)
--(axis cs:0.815719832276248,-0.2)
--(axis cs:0.828522382496481,-0.4)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-0.469417836589817)
--(axis cs:0.735009838101298,-0.6)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,-0.74437171077823)
--(axis cs:0.525600164994483,-0.8)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,-0.87363905087683)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,-0.940989387117833)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,-0.962571874201965)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,-0.941213000786582)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,-0.874374741375032)
--(axis cs:-0.527871199326969,-0.8)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,-0.747727339738553)
--(axis cs:-0.743286973637845,-0.6)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,-0.506311735138795)
--(axis cs:-0.853725167440467,-0.4)
--(axis cs:-0.884274283626111,-0.2)
--(axis cs:-0.818868660883478,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,0.0186881825156651)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,0.168662141917144)
--(axis cs:-0.530674445631826,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,0.23154068236209)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.24904519304177)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.239321434365805)
--(axis cs:0.0267921823889057,0.235036123267517);

\path [draw=color0] (axis cs:-0.210693337438727,0.475499860656936)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.47512354764157)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.451989632978374)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.415270261634482)
--(axis cs:0.262395213163633,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.360514332635342)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.292842288915109)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.219021598764685)
--(axis cs:0.850070860206972,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.110663085213272)
--(axis cs:1.18941088802103,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:1.2,-0.013169167424136)
--(axis cs:1.36548971803206,-0.2)
--(axis cs:1.4,-0.346467622575033)
--(axis cs:1.41525810991771,-0.4)
--(axis cs:1.4,-0.489444226852259)
--(axis cs:1.38199143990406,-0.6)
--(axis cs:1.29216926137998,-0.8)
--(axis cs:1.2,-0.931595584483009)
--(axis cs:1.14666573217078,-1)
--(axis cs:1,-1.1473960914153)
--(axis cs:0.934693420661718,-1.2)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-1.29699727829404)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,-1.39852527998022)
--(axis cs:0.595839505563786,-1.4)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,-1.47191516525735)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,-1.51267039459792)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,-1.52572140781982)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,-1.51267240705617)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,-1.4719207782619)
--(axis cs:-0.595871339386656,-1.4)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,-1.39853707578685)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,-1.2970588290035)
--(axis cs:-0.934854164251807,-1.2)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,-1.14768701218976)
--(axis cs:-1.14744641730709,-1)
--(axis cs:-1.2,-0.933835512649455)
--(axis cs:-1.29554637393258,-0.8)
--(axis cs:-1.39376006649381,-0.6)
--(axis cs:-1.4,-0.579241583733314)
--(axis cs:-1.45647300500947,-0.4)
--(axis cs:-1.47217049481286,-0.2)
--(axis cs:-1.42516327473369,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:-1.4,0.0364003404051473)
--(axis cs:-1.28502957848119,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:-1.2,0.259489871073525)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,0.371718283041655)
--(axis cs:-0.977742482836657,0.38087808590509);

\path [draw=color1] (axis cs:-3,0.206974385990362)
--(axis cs:-2.8,0.272249649738701)
--(axis cs:-2.6,0.343047530407831)
--(axis cs:-2.45897845826387,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:-2.4,0.414236302291867)
--(axis cs:-2.2,0.475884000676378)
--(axis cs:-2,0.534685582363821)
--(axis cs:-1.8,0.588367389086595)
--(axis cs:-1.75929606303811,0.6)
--(axis cs:-1.6,0.637567181209119)
--(axis cs:-1.4,0.677721334340349)
--(axis cs:-1.2,0.706952043503571)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,0.724693406935834)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,0.730639253156884)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,0.724693406935834)
--(axis cs:-0.535064922547634,0.718933222892911);

\path [draw=color1] (axis cs:0.1294317979123,0.604700139883726)
--(axis cs:0.147941147432604,0.6)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.588367389086594)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.534685582363819)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.475884000676376)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.414236302291865)
--(axis cs:0.846589562443343,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.343047530407829)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.2722496497387)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.206974385990361)
--(axis cs:1.42534615679419,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.123064847075952)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.0489735860560733)
--(axis cs:1.96376189331658,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:2,-0.0223633857628107)
--(axis cs:2.2,-0.112411172304082)
--(axis cs:2.4,-0.180343681777905)
--(axis cs:2.48464328689722,-0.2)
--(axis cs:2.6,-0.270727216812581)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,-0.351488014764287);

\path [draw=color2] (axis cs:2.80000000000001,1.59508319747179)
--(axis cs:2.78414468463797,1.6)
--(axis cs:2.6,1.65659309650198)
--(axis cs:2.4,1.70263588582221)
--(axis cs:2.2,1.73581851781277)
--(axis cs:2.13644892408932,1.74299337772135);

\path [draw=color2] (axis cs:1.46226876810439,1.77513221330229)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.77428316926718)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.76364172235736)
--(axis cs:1,1.74472790945252)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,1.71689848682935)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,1.6792916183094)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,1.63092742517328)
--(axis cs:0.291236985088994,1.6)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,1.57385871739495)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,1.50839258100721)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,1.43080984143742)
--(axis cs:-0.276013716607349,1.4)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,1.29769385736902)
--(axis cs:-0.515614645380936,1.2)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,1.05205114513697)
--(axis cs:-0.36757320453973,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.937900369968826)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.85428099767751)
--(axis cs:0.113500409229381,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.775075045244441)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.711580024577544)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.644955318852408)
--(axis cs:0.733090187895089,0.6)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.579513531757773)
--(axis cs:1,0.520842132115612)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.46695540676496)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.420106012981296)
--(axis cs:1.50958495477461,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.379260124065904)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.34766644131992)
--(axis cs:2,0.330090567697984)
--(axis cs:2.2,0.327562237877321)
--(axis cs:2.4,0.341204591549618)
--(axis cs:2.6,0.372605415870115)
--(axis cs:2.71373184502007,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,0.421094767411591);

\path [draw=color3] (axis cs:2.80000000000001,1.03640584482182)
--(axis cs:2.71439495102587,1.2)
--(axis cs:2.6,1.27170039735202)
--(axis cs:2.4,1.37182319463535)
--(axis cs:2.32842504086453,1.4)
--(axis cs:2.2,1.43707617925604)
--(axis cs:2,1.47933226575322)
--(axis cs:1.8,1.50654932359061)
--(axis cs:1.6,1.52039283200359)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.52167854127354)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.51049518301688)
--(axis cs:1,1.48627528858315)
--(axis cs:0.926958185545041,1.4722384724419);

\path [draw=color3] (axis cs:0.30983895688028,1.22166775912527)
--(axis cs:0.278446654287813,1.2)
--(axis cs:0.321734454802454,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.958444737344827)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.847294356254381)
--(axis cs:0.68446413428314,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.762113914178092)
--(axis cs:1,0.701418819223192)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.648024373292493)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.605044792581313)
--(axis cs:1.43655326427328,0.6)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.579186830226458)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.56858215596522)
--(axis cs:2,0.574642750880586)
--(axis cs:2.2,0.599612298829191)
--(axis cs:2.20188275646363,0.6)
--(axis cs:2.4,0.65553243790849)
--(axis cs:2.6,0.742529288949708)
--(axis cs:2.70019673404058,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,0.966902368918258);

\path [draw=red!50.0!black] (axis cs:1.46411784156425,1.25794018233102)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.25922455781096)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.2393333143328)
--(axis cs:1.02904927782622,1.2)
--(axis cs:1,1.15388047040927)
--(axis cs:0.945522999470894,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.973751166772145)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.895105266301452)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.837798043840447)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.812796457574686)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.832918124817077)
--(axis cs:2,0.912311832999764)
--(axis cs:2.12086162875271,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.07367124095886,1.05107686936407);

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This should export as the following image:[image]

But does instead export as the following:
[image]

Comment: matplotlib2tikz made no attempt to export the labels, otherwise there would be a `node` somewhere.

Comment: Is there a possibility to make matplotlib2tikz export those labels? Or another way to add them except for adding them individually by hand? (hence adding `\node[label,rotate=-20,color3] at (axis cs:0.5,0 ) {-1000};` for every label and figuring out the position by hand). Or is there an option to export the position and rotation of the labels in python such that I can easiliy add the labels to the pgfplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add labels by hand, just copy the last and first point of a continuous contour, or the last and first point in the gap between two halves of a discontinuous contour, into a new path with a node in the middle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]

\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.161290322580645,1,0.806451612903226}
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.3,1}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1,0.407407407407408,0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.806451612903226,1,0.161290322580645}

\begin{axis}[
title={Simplest default with labels},
xmin=-3, xmax=2.80000000000001,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,% changed ymax from 1.8 to 2
axis on top
]
\path [draw=blue!50.0!black] (axis cs:0.718531200553679,-0.0767608872850903)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-0.179470474200398)
--(axis cs:0.815719832276248,-0.2)
--(axis cs:0.828522382496481,-0.4)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-0.469417836589817)
--(axis cs:0.735009838101298,-0.6)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,-0.74437171077823)
--(axis cs:0.525600164994483,-0.8)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,-0.87363905087683)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,-0.940989387117833)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,-0.962571874201965)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,-0.941213000786582)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,-0.874374741375032)
--(axis cs:-0.527871199326969,-0.8)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,-0.747727339738553)
--(axis cs:-0.743286973637845,-0.6)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,-0.506311735138795)
--(axis cs:-0.853725167440467,-0.4)
--(axis cs:-0.884274283626111,-0.2)
--(axis cs:-0.818868660883478,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,0.0186881825156651)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,0.168662141917144)
--(axis cs:-0.530674445631826,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,0.23154068236209)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.24904519304177)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.239321434365805)
--(axis cs:0.0267921823889057,0.235036123267517);

\path (axis cs:0.0267921823889057,0.235036123267517)
   --(axis cs:0.718531200553679,-0.0767608872850903)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {-1000};

\path [draw=color0] (axis cs:-0.210693337438727,0.475499860656936)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.47512354764157)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.451989632978374)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.415270261634482)
--(axis cs:0.262395213163633,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.360514332635342)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.292842288915109)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.219021598764685)
--(axis cs:0.850070860206972,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.110663085213272)
--(axis cs:1.18941088802103,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:1.2,-0.013169167424136)
--(axis cs:1.36548971803206,-0.2)
--(axis cs:1.4,-0.346467622575033)
--(axis cs:1.41525810991771,-0.4)
--(axis cs:1.4,-0.489444226852259)
--(axis cs:1.38199143990406,-0.6)
--(axis cs:1.29216926137998,-0.8)
--(axis cs:1.2,-0.931595584483009)
--(axis cs:1.14666573217078,-1)
--(axis cs:1,-1.1473960914153)
--(axis cs:0.934693420661718,-1.2)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,-1.29699727829404)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,-1.39852527998022)
--(axis cs:0.595839505563786,-1.4)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,-1.47191516525735)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,-1.51267039459792)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,-1.52572140781982)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,-1.51267240705617)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,-1.4719207782619)
--(axis cs:-0.595871339386656,-1.4)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,-1.39853707578685)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,-1.2970588290035)
--(axis cs:-0.934854164251807,-1.2)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,-1.14768701218976)
--(axis cs:-1.14744641730709,-1)
--(axis cs:-1.2,-0.933835512649455)
--(axis cs:-1.29554637393258,-0.8)
--(axis cs:-1.39376006649381,-0.6)
--(axis cs:-1.4,-0.579241583733314)
--(axis cs:-1.45647300500947,-0.4)
--(axis cs:-1.47217049481286,-0.2)
--(axis cs:-1.42516327473369,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:-1.4,0.0364003404051473)
--(axis cs:-1.28502957848119,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:-1.2,0.259489871073525)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,0.371718283041655)
--(axis cs:-0.977742482836657,0.38087808590509);

\path (axis cs:-0.977742482836657,0.38087808590509)
   --(axis cs:-0.210693337438727,0.475499860656936)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {-500};

\path [draw=color1] (axis cs:-3,0.206974385990362)
--(axis cs:-2.8,0.272249649738701)
--(axis cs:-2.6,0.343047530407831)
--(axis cs:-2.45897845826387,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:-2.4,0.414236302291867)
--(axis cs:-2.2,0.475884000676378)
--(axis cs:-2,0.534685582363821)
--(axis cs:-1.8,0.588367389086595)
--(axis cs:-1.75929606303811,0.6)
--(axis cs:-1.6,0.637567181209119)
--(axis cs:-1.4,0.677721334340349)
--(axis cs:-1.2,0.706952043503571)
--(axis cs:-0.999999999999998,0.724693406935834)
--(axis cs:-0.799999999999998,0.730639253156884)
--(axis cs:-0.599999999999998,0.724693406935834)
--(axis cs:-0.535064922547634,0.718933222892911);

\path (axis cs:-0.535064922547634,0.718933222892911)
   --(axis cs:0.1294317979123,0.604700139883726)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {0};

\path [draw=color1] (axis cs:0.1294317979123,0.604700139883726)
--(axis cs:0.147941147432604,0.6)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.588367389086594)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.534685582363819)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.475884000676376)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.414236302291865)
--(axis cs:0.846589562443343,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.343047530407829)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.2722496497387)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.206974385990361)
--(axis cs:1.42534615679419,0.199999999999999)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.123064847075952)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.0489735860560733)
--(axis cs:1.96376189331658,-4.44089209850063e-16)
--(axis cs:2,-0.0223633857628107)
--(axis cs:2.2,-0.112411172304082)
--(axis cs:2.4,-0.180343681777905)
--(axis cs:2.48464328689722,-0.2)
--(axis cs:2.6,-0.270727216812581)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,-0.351488014764287);

\path [draw=color2] (axis cs:2.80000000000001,1.59508319747179)
--(axis cs:2.78414468463797,1.6)
--(axis cs:2.6,1.65659309650198)
--(axis cs:2.4,1.70263588582221)
--(axis cs:2.2,1.73581851781277)
--(axis cs:2.13644892408932,1.74299337772135);

\path (axis cs:2.13644892408932,1.74299337772135)
   --(axis cs:1.46226876810439,1.77513221330229)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {500};

\path [draw=color2] (axis cs:1.46226876810439,1.77513221330229)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.77428316926718)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.76364172235736)
--(axis cs:1,1.74472790945252)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,1.71689848682935)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,1.6792916183094)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,1.63092742517328)
--(axis cs:0.291236985088994,1.6)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,1.57385871739495)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,1.50839258100721)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,1.43080984143742)
--(axis cs:-0.276013716607349,1.4)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,1.29769385736902)
--(axis cs:-0.515614645380936,1.2)
--(axis cs:-0.399999999999998,1.05205114513697)
--(axis cs:-0.36757320453973,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:-0.199999999999998,0.937900369968826)
--(axis cs:2.66453525910038e-15,0.85428099767751)
--(axis cs:0.113500409229381,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.200000000000003,0.775075045244441)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.711580024577544)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.644955318852408)
--(axis cs:0.733090187895089,0.6)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.579513531757773)
--(axis cs:1,0.520842132115612)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.46695540676496)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.420106012981296)
--(axis cs:1.50958495477461,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.379260124065904)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.34766644131992)
--(axis cs:2,0.330090567697984)
--(axis cs:2.2,0.327562237877321)
--(axis cs:2.4,0.341204591549618)
--(axis cs:2.6,0.372605415870115)
--(axis cs:2.71373184502007,0.399999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,0.421094767411591);

\path [draw=color3] (axis cs:2.80000000000001,1.03640584482182)
--(axis cs:2.71439495102587,1.2)
--(axis cs:2.6,1.27170039735202)
--(axis cs:2.4,1.37182319463535)
--(axis cs:2.32842504086453,1.4)
--(axis cs:2.2,1.43707617925604)
--(axis cs:2,1.47933226575322)
--(axis cs:1.8,1.50654932359061)
--(axis cs:1.6,1.52039283200359)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.52167854127354)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.51049518301688)
--(axis cs:1,1.48627528858315)
--(axis cs:0.926958185545041,1.4722384724419);

\path (axis cs:0.926958185545041,1.4722384724419)
   --(axis cs:0.30983895688028,1.22166775912527)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {1000};

\path [draw=color3] (axis cs:0.30983895688028,1.22166775912527)
--(axis cs:0.278446654287813,1.2)
--(axis cs:0.321734454802454,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.400000000000003,0.958444737344827)
--(axis cs:0.600000000000003,0.847294356254381)
--(axis cs:0.68446413428314,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:0.800000000000003,0.762113914178092)
--(axis cs:1,0.701418819223192)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.648024373292493)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.605044792581313)
--(axis cs:1.43655326427328,0.6)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.579186830226458)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.56858215596522)
--(axis cs:2,0.574642750880586)
--(axis cs:2.2,0.599612298829191)
--(axis cs:2.20188275646363,0.6)
--(axis cs:2.4,0.65553243790849)
--(axis cs:2.6,0.742529288949708)
--(axis cs:2.70019673404058,0.799999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.80000000000001,0.966902368918258);

\path [draw=red!50.0!black] (axis cs:1.46411784156425,1.25794018233102)
--(axis cs:1.4,1.25922455781096)
--(axis cs:1.2,1.2393333143328)
--(axis cs:1.02904927782622,1.2)
--(axis cs:1,1.15388047040927)
--(axis cs:0.945522999470894,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:1,0.973751166772145)
--(axis cs:1.2,0.895105266301452)
--(axis cs:1.4,0.837798043840447)
--(axis cs:1.6,0.812796457574686)
--(axis cs:1.8,0.832918124817077)
--(axis cs:2,0.912311832999764)
--(axis cs:2.12086162875271,0.999999999999999)
--(axis cs:2.07367124095886,1.05107686936407);

\path (axis cs:2.07367124095886,1.05107686936407)
   --(axis cs:1.46411784156425,1.25794018233102)
   node[midway,sloped,above,inner sep=0pt] {1500};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]